# How to copy a folder in the same directory with different name?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to copy the folder and rename it.

How to do it with powershell?

Copy-item fails as i am trying to paste it in the same directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Copy-Item Original Original-Copy -recurse
```

So it copies the contents too.

Comment: If the folder "Original-Copy" already exists then Copy-Item places a copy of the folder within "Original-Copy" named "Original". Delete any existing "Original-Copy" folders first to prevent this.

Answer (score 2):

Just give the destination a new name. This worked for me.

> Copy-Item Original Original-Copy

Copied the folder named "Original" to a folder named "Original-Copy".